# Add links to specific points of a flash video

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, cs3

I am attempting to insert links into a video as it is played back. So that a link and descriptive text appear either on or below a video as the narrator movies between subjects. I'm work with a flash video. I think I need to do this using ActionScript (I'm using CS3) but I've never worked with action script.

Could someone provide a good link or basic instructions to help a total ActionScript newbie accomplish this?

Any help is *greatly* appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place to start if you are going to get into Flash video is the [Video Technology center on the Adobe site](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/video/). This has loads of information on Flash video, as well as news on any new updates and tutorials.

There is a good tutorial there at the moment about [Using Adobe Media Encoder CS4](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/video_encoder/). There is a section in that tutorial about [Cue Points (section 5)](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/video_encoder/#section5) that you will want to have a look at to help with your problem. That section (and the rest of the tutorial) will help you much more than I can explain here.

I would strongly recommend reading the whole tutorial, but "**Cue Points**" are what you are looking for.

Good luck!